# how to replace a word combined with special character in vi editor

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I am exploring vi editor,

I want to replace `_` (underscore) with `[]` bracket.

Example: `data_0` needs to be replaced with `data[0]`.

I know basic replace command in vi. How can I replace in this situation?

Comment: sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below command should work. It captures the index following the `_` using parenthesis.

`:%s/_\(\d\+\)/[\1]`

`\1` provides the first captured group which is the number following `_`.

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on [gaganso's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593127/gaganso) answer, and explain what

```
:%s/_\(\d\+\)/[\1]
```

means.

- `:` its an ex command
- `%` across the entire file
- `s` it's a substitution

substitutions come in the following format (see `:help :s`)

```
:[range]s/[find]/[replace]/[flags]
```

we've already handled the range (its global, thanks to `%`), now we just need to explain what's inside the `[find]` and the `[replace]` blocks.

the **`[find]`** part of this regex is

```
_\(\d\+\)
```

and it says

- `_` find an underscore
- `\(` open a new grouping (escaped brackets indicates that whatever we find inside should be 'saved' so we can put it back in later)
- `\d+` look for any number of digits in a row
- `\)` close grouping (so the part that we 'saved' for later is any number of digits in a row, that come after an underscore. In your example this would be the `0` of `data_0`

And the **`[replace]`** section

- `[` put down a square bracket
- `\1` put down whatever it is we saved in our grouping (the 1 indicates we are taking whatever was found in the first grouping, we also happen to only have one grouping anyway)
- `]` put down another square bracket

And there you have it! The vim regex for finding an underscore followed by a number, and replacing it with the same number inside square brackets!